# Does the garbage collector count this as a collectable object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Given a string

```
String x = "hello";
```

As far as I remember, `x` now is a constant with a reference but when in the middle of the code I change value to

```
x = "hey";
```

`hello` stays stuck in the memory and the GC frees it. Is it true ? If not, could you explain more how the GC work?

Comment: That's... complicated. `"hello"` and `"hey"` are both compile-time constants. For example, if both lines are written one after the other, the first constant might not even be created (due to compile time optimization). Furhtermore, all compile-time constants `"hello"` reference the same `String`-object (due to string interning). So if we have more than one compile-time constant `"hello"`, it is not be sufficient to only dereference one of them.

Comment: @Turing85 BINGO!!! I had forgotten that term "compile-time" constants. This is something I learned in Assembly Language. And yes... it is indeed complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I remember, `x` now is a constant

No. The reference is not a constant. It is a reference to an immutable, but the reference itself (the "pointer") is not (crediting Turing85 for the clarification). For `x` to be considered a constant, it needs to be declared with the keyword `final` (then the reference itself will be a constant). For example, `final String x = "hello";`. Because it is not a constant, it allows you to change the reference later on in the code `x = "hey";`. THAT SAID, because of how Java manages strings (and other immutables), "hello" and "hey" are indeed constants. They are "permanent" members of the String pool. Meaning that, their life cycle is the same as the life of your program. I think there are ways change this, but by default I am pretty sure this is the case. So, if you create multiple objects with the same `String` value:

```
String a = "hello"; // will add "hello" to String pool if it doesn't exist there
String b = "hello"; // finds "hello" in the string pool and returns back the same reference to this variable
String c = "hello"; // same as `b` above
```

However, if you create a new `String` using the copy constructor:

```
String d = new String("hello"); // Will add new "hello" to heap even though it already exist in string pool. (Thanks Holger!)
```

Explaining in detail how the GC works is not very easy to explain; especially in a single SO post. I don't even fully understand it myself. But, since the purpose of the pool is to eliminate the need to create "infinite" copies of the same thing over and over, "hello" and "hey" won't be garbage-collected. As for the variable `x`, it will be handled by the GC depending on many factors, one of which is scope.  Also, there is no guarantee as to when (if ever) the GC will cleanup an unused resource.

I think this is accurate, albeit somewhat ambiguous or incomplete. But at a high-level, this is how GC will work in this case to the best of my knowledge.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @Holger for bringing this to my attention. When a *String Literal* is assigned to a variable, it will first look for such value in the **String Pool** to see if such string exists. If it doesn't, it creates it and assigns it to the variable. HOWEVER, when a string is created with the **`new`** operator, it will add the new string JUST into *Heap Memory*. That's the main difference between assigning string literals vs. new strings to a variable.

Comment: "*The reference is not a constant. It is an immutable reference.*" - This could be misinterpreted. It is a reference to an immutable, but the reference itself is not immutable - that is, was the `final` keyword does.

Comment: @Turing85 I can see that now. Thanks for pointing that out. That's exactly what I meant. When I wrote it, sounded good at the time. :)

Comment: `new String("hello")` does *not* add a new string to the pool. It simply creates a new string. Regarding the lifetime, objects representing constants like `"hello"` are referenced by the code which uses them. So they live at least as long as the code exists, for ordinary code loaded by the application class loader, this means the entire lifetime of the application. For code loaded by a custom class loader, it’s possible that the loader and all of its classes get collected together, which would stop them from holding references to such constants.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the clarification. You are right, `new String()` adds the string into _heap_ and not the _string pool_.

Comment: To be precise, all objects are stored in the heap memory. The string pool is just an additional table of references to some of the string objects.